# Build Dictionary and List from Numpy Ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I wanted to create a dictionary using 2D ndarray for some millions of data.

Looking for a pythonic and performant way to achieve this

**My ndarray:**

format: [id, origin_lat, origin_lon, dest_lat,dest_lon, distance]

```
my_array = np.array([[245, 32.45,63.89,72.1,63.57,123.45],
[246, 61.73,42.71,75.54,-81.69,16.32]])
```

**Expected Output:**

```
my_dict = {
        245: {
            'origin_lat_lon': {
                'lat': 32.45,
                'lon': 63.89
            },
            'dest_lat_lon': {
                'lat': 72.1,
                'lon': 63.57
            },
            'distance': 123.45
        },
        246: {
            'origin_lat_lon': {
                'lat': 61.73,
                'lon': 42.71
            },
            'dest_lat_lon': {
                'lat': 75.54,
                'lon': -81.69
            },
            'distance': 16.32
        }
    }

my_list = [{'lat': 32.45, 'lon': 63.89},
 {'lat': 72.1, 'lon': 63.57},
 {'lat': 61.73, 'lon': 42.71},
 {'lat': 75.54, 'lon': -81.69}]
```

**My code:**

```
my_dict = dict()
my_list = list()

for arr in my_array:
    origin_lat_lon = {'lat': arr[1],
                            'lon': arr[2]}
    dest_lat_lon  = {'lat': arr[3],
                  'lon': arr[4]}
    value = {'origin_lat_lon':origin_lat_lon,'dest_lat_lon':dest_lat_lon,'distance':arr[5]}
    my_dict[int(arr[0])]=value
    my_list.append(origin_lat_lon)
    my_list.append(dest_lat_lon)
```

Comment: @Chris You are right, Just updated the expected output

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `dict` with `zip` and `slicing`.

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[245, 32.45,63.89,72.1,63.57,123.45],[246, 61.73,42.71,75.54,-81.69,16.32]])
keys = ['origin_lat', 'origin_lon', 'dest_lat','dest_lon', 'distance']
keys_2 = ['lat', 'lon']

my_dict = {}
my_list = []

for arr in my_array:
    key, vals = arr[0], arr[1:]
    my_dict[int(key)] = dict(zip(keys, vals))
    my_list.extend([[dict(zip(keys_2, vals[0:2]))],[dict(zip(keys_2, vals[2:4]))]])

print(my_dict)
print(my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
{245: {'dest_lat': 72.1,
       'dest_lon': 63.57,
       'distance': 123.45,
       'origin_lat': 32.45,
       'origin_lon': 63.89},
 246: {'dest_lat': 75.54,
       'dest_lon': -81.69,
       'distance': 16.32,
       'origin_lat': 61.73,
       'origin_lon': 42.71}}
[[{'lat': 32.45, 'lon': 63.89}],
 [{'lat': 72.1, 'lon': 63.57}],
 [{'lat': 61.73, 'lon': 42.71}],
 [{'lat': 75.54, 'lon': -81.69}]]
```

Comment: The regular python for loop is slow for a millions of data. I was looking for something like numpy.vectorize or anything where you explicitly don't loop the array

Comment: `numpy` vectorize means using compiled numpy methods, which are mostly computational.  You are creating Python objects - lists and dictionary, and ultimately a `json` string.  There isn't compiled numpy code for that.

Comment: @min2bro note, `numpy.vectorize` is just a Python for loop, it is provide for convenience, not performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code wrapped in a function, times:

```
In [220]: timeit foo(my_array)                                                  
7.14 µs ± 17.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

converting the array to a list cuts time in half.  `tolist()` is a (relatively) fast method for converting an array to a nested list.  Iterating on a list is faster than iterating on an array:

```
In [221]: timeit foo(my_array.tolist())                                         
2.68 µs ± 14.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Rakesh's version, is somewhat slower (I haven't identified why):

```
In [222]: timeit rakesh(my_array)                                               
18.5 µs ± 63.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [223]: timeit rakesh(my_array.tolist())                                      
9.49 µs ± 26.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Chris's pandas version is quite a bit slower.  `pandas` does have a nice interface to/from dictionaries, but apparently it isn't fast.  It probably is pure Python, and looses speed by being general purpose.

```
In [224]: timeit foo_pd(my_array)                                               
3.35 ms ± 5.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Python dictionaries are efficient for what they do, but they still have to be accessed key by key.  `numpy` does not have of its own compiled code for working with dictionaries.

===

Your array could be cast as a structured array.  With that columns are replaced fields, which are accessed by name.  So it's more dictionary-like, though probably not any better for creating a `json` output.  (And it's not a speed tool)

```
In [225]: dt = np.dtype([('id',int),('origin_lat',float),('origin_lon',float),('
     ...: dest_lat',float),('dest_lon',float),('distance',float)])              
In [226]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf                                   

In [228]: sarr =rf.unstructured_to_structured(my_array, dt)                     
In [229]: sarr                                                                  
Out[229]: 
array([(245, 32.45, 63.89, 72.1 ,  63.57, 123.45),
       (246, 61.73, 42.71, 75.54, -81.69,  16.32)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('origin_lat', '<f8'), ('origin_lon', '<f8'), ('dest_lat', '<f8'), ('dest_lon', '<f8'), ('distance', '<f8')])

In [230]: sarr['dest_lon']                                                      
Out[230]: array([ 63.57, -81.69])

In [236]: timeit sarr =rf.unstructured_to_structured(my_array, dt)              
46.3 µs ± 1.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: The pandas version is using `.apply` which is basically just a regular old loop. Except this approach has all the extra overhead of creating the dataframe etc

Comment: None of these solutions really speed up the entire computation. Even my solution in terms of timeit is close to both these solutions. My question was to optimize the code to run it on million data points.

Comment: And my point is that since you are creating Python dictionaries, there isn't a way of significantly speeding this up, at least not in the usual `numpy` sense.  I don't know if one of the compiler tools, `numba` or `cython` can help.